# Where Condition in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a below dataset,

```
+---------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3  | Exspense1 | Exspense2 | Exspense3 |
+---------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| null    | null    | null     | 175935.40 |   2557400 |         0 |
| null    | null    | 20160511 | 94598.40  |  13050360 |         0 |
| null    | null    | 20160512 | 81337.00  |  12523645 |         0 |
| null    | Item1   | null     | 24955.20  |   4206475 |         0 |
| null    | Item1   | 20160511 | 14143.30  |   2357534 |         0 |
| null    | Item1   | 20160512 | 10811.90  |   1848941 |         0 |
| null    | Item2   | null     | 26725.20  |   2188031 |         0 |
| null    | Item2   | 20160511 | 17807.50  |   1400011 |         0 |
| null    | Item2   | 20160512 | 8917.70   |    788020 |         0 |
| null    | Item3   | null     | 19234.30  |   2787529 |         0 |
| null    | Item3   | 20160511 | 8204.30   |   1162487 |         0 |
| null    | Item3   | 20160512 | 11030.00  |   1625042 |         0 |
| null    | Item4   | null     | 85239.20  |  13848186 |         0 |
| null    | Item4   | 20160511 | 47324.10  |   7157838 |         0 |
| null    | Item4   | 20160512 | 37915.10  |   6690348 |         0 |
| null    | Item5   | null     | 19781.50  |   2543784 |         0 |
| null    | Item5   | 20160511 | 7119.209  |     72490 |         0 |
| null    | Item5   | 20160512 | 12662.30  |   1571294 |         0 |
| Shop1   | null    | null     | 35.70     |     10577 |         0 |
| Shop1   | null    | 20160512 | 35.701    |      0577 |         0 |
| Shop1   | Item1   | null     | 34.40     |     10538 |         0 |
| Shop1   | Item1   | 20160512 | 34.401    |      0538 |         0 |
| Shop1   | Item3   | null     | 1.30      |        39 |         0 |
| Shop1   | Item3   | 20160512 | 1.30      |        39 |         0 |
| Shop2   | null    | null     | 10757.30  |   2163921 |         0 |
| Shop2   | null    | 20160511 | 6672.20   |   1286947 |         0 |
| Shop2   | null    | 20160512 | 4085.10   |    876974 |         0 |
| Shop2   | Item1   | null     | 1510.30   |    370818 |         0 |
| Shop2   | Item1   | 20160511 | 752.101   |     90052 |         0 |
| Shop2   | Item1   | 20160512 | 758.201   |     80766 |         0 |
+---------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm following a check foreg: `boolean sumCheck` for each column below,
where I have to loop through each column. Now,

1.for Column1 if `sumCheck is true` I have to filter lines where Column1 is not null and same row prevoius column is null, Since Column1 is first column so no filter,

2. For Column 2:
   if check is true,
   Then I have to filter rows where *Column2 is not null* and *Column1 is null*
   that means I dont want the rows where `(Column2 is not null and Column1 is null)`
   I have to get below,

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th><th>Exspense1</th><th>Exspense2</th><th>Exspense3</th></tr><tr><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>175935.40</td><td>2557400</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>20160511</td><td>94598.40</td><td>13050360</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>20160512</td><td>81337.00</td><td>12523645</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>35.70</td><td>10577</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>null</td><td>20160512</td><td>35.701</td><td>0577</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item1</td><td>null</td><td>34.40</td><td>10538</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item1</td><td>20160512</td><td>34.401</td><td>0538</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item3</td><td>null</td><td>1.30</td><td>39</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item3</td><td>20160512</td><td>1.30</td><td>39</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>10757.30</td><td>2163921</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>null</td><td>20160511</td><td>6672.20</td><td>1286947</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>null</td><td>20160512</td><td>4085.10</td><td>876974</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>Item1</td><td>null</td><td>1510.30</td><td>370818</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>Item1</td><td>20160511</td><td>752.101</td><td>90052</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>Item1</td><td>20160512</td><td>758.201</td><td>80766</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

3. For Column 3 if check is true the I have to filter the dataset so that where Column3 is 
   I have to remove rows where Column3 is not null and Column2 is null;
   So that I get below ,

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th><th>Exspense1</th><th>Exspense2</th><th>Exspense3</th></tr><tr><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>175935.40</td><td>2557400</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>35.70</td><td>10577</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item1</td><td>null</td><td>34.40</td><td>10538</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item1</td><td>20160512</td><td>34.401</td><td>0538</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item3</td><td>null</td><td>1.30</td><td>39</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop1</td><td>Item3</td><td>20160512</td><td>1.30</td><td>39</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>null</td><td>null</td><td>10757.30</td><td>2163921</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>Item1</td><td>null</td><td>1510.30</td><td>370818</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>Item1</td><td>20160511</td><td>752.101</td><td>90052</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Shop2</td><td>Item1</td><td>20160512</td><td>758.201</td><td>80766</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I currently I do below steps:

for Each Column Size I loop and see the flag;
I start from Second Column:
for Second Col:

```
val exceptDf=dataset.filter("Column2 is not null and Column 1 is null");
```

for Third Col:

```
val  exceptDf3=exceptDf.union(dataset.filter("Column3 is not null and Column 2 is null"));
```

and Finally i Do

```
dataset.except(exceptDf3);
```

Since I'm doing using `union except filter` I just wanted to see if there's any method or `filter` only that would avoid me from using the `unions` and `exept` functions.

Please help me in getting the desired results.

Comment: please share what you've tried and improve your explanation a little bit more

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I updated

Comment: what is sumCheck? and what do you mean by "for Column1 if sumCheck is true" ? and this one "Since Column1 is first column so no filter"? there a lots of unclarified points. I want you to explain all of them in detail with examples and please remove the code snippets. Instead just put simple texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spark `where` or `filter` function.

**For sample dataset:**

```
+----+---+----+---+
|  c1| c2|  c3| c4|
+----+---+----+---+
| 2.2|v21|   1|foo|
|null|v22|   2|bar|
| 4.4|v23|   3|baz|
| 5.5|v24|null|foo|
+----+---+----+---+
```

I have to check the condition: c2 != null and c1 == null and c4 != null and c3 == null:

**Using `where`:**

```
df.where("(not(c2 is not null and c1 is null)) and (not(c4 is not null and c3 is null))")
```

**Using `filter`:**

```
df.filter( !(col("c2").isNotNull && col("c1").isNull) && !(col("c4").isNotNull && col("c3").isNull) )
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|2.2|v21|  1|foo|
|4.4|v23|  3|baz|
+---+---+---+---+
```